# JS and CSS menu stopped working on webgl page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple nav made up of several icons, when you click on one JS and CSS create a slide-in style menu. It has been working up till now and for some reason it isn't anymore, I'm not sure if it is something to do with the webgl on the page or if it is another reason.

website: www.explorecanterbury.co.uk

CSS

```
.photo-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 370px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 700px;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
  display:none;
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 4px #999;
}
.nav-toggle-2 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
 }
.nav-toggle-3 {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
}

.information-menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display:none;
  background: #ddd;
  text-align: left;
  box-shadow: 1px 4px 4px #999;
}

.LocIcon {
  background-image:url(/images/select.png);
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  display: block;
}

.photosIcon {
  background-image:url(/images/photos.png);
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  display: block;
}

.infoIcon {
  background-image:url(/images/information.png);
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  display: block;
}
.searchIcon {
  background-image:url(/images/search.png);
  width:24px;
  height:24px;
  display: block;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function() {
      $('.nav-toggle-3').on('click', function() {
        $(".information-menu").animate({width:'toggle'},200);
      });

      $('.nav-toggle-2').on('click', function() {
        $(".photo-menu").animate({width:'toggle'},200);
      });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="z-index:6;">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle hidden-xs" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="LocIcon"></span></li>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Museums and Galleries</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option3" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Landmarks</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option4" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Shopping</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option5" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Churches</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option6" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox"/>&nbsp;Tours and Guides</a></li>
            </ul>
            <li><span class="photosIcon nav-toggle-2 hidden-xs"></span></li>
            <li><span class="infoIcon nav-toggle-3 hidden-xs"></span></li>
            <li><span class="searchIcon hidden-xs"></span></li>
            </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form hidden-xs" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            </div>
          </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: intersects[ 0 ].object is undefined in the onDocumentMouseUp method.

Answer (score 1):

```
function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {

    // create a Ray with origin at the mouse position
    //   and direction into the scene (camera direction)
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( mouse.x, mouse.y, 1 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

    // create an array containing all objects in the scene with which the ray intersects
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( targetList, true);

    if ( intersects[ 0 ].object.name === "Canterbury Tale")
    {
        alert("Canterbury Tale has been clicked!");
    }

    if ( intersects[ 0 ].object.name === "Westgate")
    {
        alert("Westgate has been clicked!");
    }   

    if ( intersects[ 0 ].object.name === "Cathedral")
    {
        document.getElementById('canttaleDiv').style.display = "block"; 
    }   
    }
```

Analyzing your code and this directly showed up in the console. When you click on your navbar the `onDocumentMouseUp` method get called somehow, therefore it tries to analyze `intersects[ 0 ].object.name`, fails, and nothing happen. You might want to put ( or bind ) this method on the wrapper with the 3D models, not on the whole document.